# Test method delete doesnt work

Tags: testing, mocking, delete-operator

Hi I want to test service method delete but it doesn't work:

This is my service method:

```
public Optional<PersonDto> deletePerson(Long id) {
    Assert.notNull(id, "id can't be null");
    Optional<Person> personOptional = personRepository.findById(id);
    personRepository.delete(personOptional.orElse(new Person()));
    return personOptional.map(p -> modelMapper.map(p, PersonDto.class));
}
```

And this is my test for this method:

```
@Test
public void shouldDeletePersonById() {
    personService.deletePerson(1l);
    Mockito.verify(personRepository, times(1)).deleteById(1l);
}
```

This is an error:

Wanted but not invoked:

```
personRepository.deleteById(1L);
-> at com.softwaremind.crew.people.service.PersonServiceTest.shouldDeletePersonById(PersonServiceTest.java:68)
```

However, there were exactly 2 interactions with this mock:

```
personRepository.findById(1L);
-> at com.softwaremind.crew.people.service.PersonService.deletePerson(PersonService.java:69)

personRepository.delete(
    Person{id=0, firstName='null', lastName='null', location='null', email='null', status='null', role='null', createdOn=null, modifiedOn=null}
);
-> at com.softwaremind.crew.people.service.PersonService.deletePerson(PersonService.java:70)
```

Ofcourse method delete in service work ok.